# Symfony 2 - Redirect Loop for login page

Tags: security, symfony, loops, redirect, fosuserbundle

I know this is an well know beginners question, but I have read docs and everything.
I get redirected to the login page and there I get directly stuck in a loop.

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: fos_user_security_login 
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: fos_user_security_login
            anonymous:  true
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    acl:
        connection: default
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
```

Would be kind if anyone could help.
Cheers,
Kartopete

Answer (score 1):

if you changed the user bundle or login method, you need to clear your cookies. I had this problem when I migrated from custom user bundle to FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your *config.yml* file, you have set:

```
fos_user:
    ...
    firewall_name:    secured_area
```

If so, your *security.yml* looks ok to me. It could be that the problem is in your routing configuration?